# Internet not working on simulator in xcode 6

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6

I've recently upgraded Xcode from version 5 to version 6. When I run the simulator, internet is not accessible. Why?

Comment: Remove comments that have become redundant.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've fixed it.   Go to iOS Simulator top menu -> Reset Content and settings -> Reset.

It works now

[image]

Comment: Yes it's working after reseting Content and settings

Comment: A system restart helped me after resetting settings!